# Adding foreign key in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I am running into an issue when adding a foreign key to a table.

```
alter table product
   add FOREIGN KEY (productid)
   references orderdetail(productid)
```

I am trying to add a foreign key within my product table that references another column `productid` that is also found within the `orderdetail` table but when I do I get the error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 46
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'.

I could reword my statement but then it would just come and say incorrect syntax near keyword constraint if I use add constraint. Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `constraint <foreign key name>`:

```
alter table product
add constraint give_it_a_name_here
FOREIGN KEY (productid)
references orderdetail(productid)
```